# rails3-amf - to_amf method not found on ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, flex4, amf

I am using the [rails3-amf](https://github.com/warhammerkid/rails3-amf) gem by warhammerkid in my Rails 3 / Flex 4 project.

AFAIK, I have correctly followed the "Getting Started" instructions from the GitHub page.

- I have added the gem lines to my Gemfile.
- I have installed the gems using `bundle install`.
- From my Flex application, I will be making the RemoteObject call to the `index` action in the `ManageMySchool::GradesController` file. This is the code in the `app/controllers/manage_my_school/grades_controller.rb` file:

> ```
> class ManageMySchool::GradesController < ApplicationController  
>     respond_to :html, :amf  
>
>     def index
>         @grade = Grade.first
>         respond_with(@grade) do |format|
>             format.amf { render :amf => @grade.to_amf }
>         end
>     end 
> end
> ```

- The name of the model which is to be serialized is called `Grade` in both the Rails project (`app/models/Grade.rb`) and the Flex project (`Grade.as` with a `RemoteAlias` set as `Grade`). In the `config/application.rb` file, I have done the class mapping this way:

> ```
> config.rails3amf.class_mapping do |m|
>     m.map :as => 'Grade', :ruby => 'Grade'  
> end
> ```

- And I have done a parameter mapping this way:

> ```
> config.rails3amf.map_params :controller => 'ManageMySchool::GradesController', :action => 'index', :params => [:authenticity_token]
> ```

### Problem

Now, when I run the server and make the RemoteObject call from Flex, I get a `to_amf undefined method` error for the `Grade` model.

If I change `Grade.first` to `Grade.all`, `@grade` would have an array of Grades. But the `undefined method` error message still mentions the Grade model. This means that the `to_amf` method is working for the Array class but not for the ActiveRecord model.

Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Is there something I have to do to "enable" the rails3-amf gem for ActiveRecord models?

I would appreciate any insights. Thanks!

### Update

@warhammerkid: Here is the output of Grade.ancestors as seen in rails console.

> ```
> ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :006 > puts Grade.ancestors
> Grade
> ActiveRecord::Base
> Paperclip::CallbackCompatability::Rails3::Running
> Paperclip::CallbackCompatability::Rails3
> Paperclip::Glue CanCan::ModelAdditions
> Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::ValidationsScope
> Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::SingleAccessToken
> Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::SessionMaintenance
> Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::RestfulAuthentication::InstanceMethods
> Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::RestfulAuthentication
> Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::PersistenceToken
> Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::PerishableToken
> Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::Password
> Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::MagicColumns
> Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::Login
> Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::LoggedInStatus
> Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::Email
> Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::Base
> ActiveRecord::Aggregations
> ActiveRecord::Transactions
> ActiveRecord::Reflection
> ActiveRecord::Serialization
> ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml
> ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
> ActiveModel::Serialization
> ActiveRecord::AutosaveAssociation
> ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes
> ActiveRecord::Associations
> ActiveRecord::AssociationPreload
> ActiveRecord::NamedScope
> ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks
> ActiveRecord::Callbacks
> ActiveModel::Observing
> ActiveRecord::Timestamp
> ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity
> ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty
> ActiveModel::Dirty
> ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion
> ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::PrimaryKey
> ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Read
> ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Write
> ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::BeforeTypeCast
> #<Module:0x1028356f0> ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Query
> ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods
> ActiveModel::AttributeMethods
> ActiveRecord::Locking::Optimistic
> ActiveRecord::Locking::Pessimistic
> ActiveRecord::Validations
> ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods
> ActiveModel::Validations
> ActiveSupport::Callbacks
> ActiveModel::Conversion
> ActiveRecord::Persistence Object
> PP::ObjectMixin Base64::Deprecated
> Base64
> ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable
> Kernel
> ```

Note that only `ActiveModel::Serialization` is there. No mention of `Rails3AMF`.

Does this mean I have to do something special to load the Rails3AMF module for the ActiveRecord models?

I am using Rails 3.0.5 with the latest version of ree. The gems are all contained in a gemset managed using rvm.

### Update 2

If I remove the `to_amf` in the `render :amf` line, then I get the following error:

> ```
> Grade Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `grades`.* FROM `grades` LIMIT 1
> Completed 200 OK in 195ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
> Sending back AMF
>
> NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
> You might have expected an instance of Array.
> The error occurred while evaluating nil.last):
>
>
> Rendered /Users/anjan/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@rb/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/>     >     action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
> Rendered /Users/anjan/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@rb/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/>     >     action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.8ms)
> Rendered /Users/anjan/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@rb/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/>     >     action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (13.6ms)
>
>
> Started POST "/amf" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Apr 15 17:03:34 +0530 2011
> Sending back AMF
> ```

### Update 3

If I manually add the line `include Rails3AMF::Serialization` at the top of the `Grade.rb` model file, then it all works. So, does this mean that I have to put this line in all my models?

I see that this is already being done in line numbers 40 - 42 in the `lib/rails3-amf/serialization.rb` file of the gem:

> ```
> # Hook into any object that includes ActiveModel::Serialization
> module ActiveModel::Serialization
>     include Rails3AMF::Serialization
> end
> ```

Why isn't this working? Should I force-load the gem when my application initializes or something?

Thanks!

### Update 4 - Solved by this workaround

Okay, I just ended up adding this code block in an initializer:

> ```
> class ActiveRecord::Base
>     include Rails3AMF::Serialization  
> end
> ```

And it is working.

@warhammerkid - Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does Grade.ancestors return? It should include ActiveModel::Serialization and Rails3AMF::Serialization if you're using ActiveRecord and the latest version of Rails.

Comment: @warhammerkid - I have included the output of Grade.ancestors in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails3AMF::Serialization, the module that adds the to_amf method, is included in ActiveModel::Serialization when Rails3-AMF loads. If it's somehow not being included even though the code is running and ActiveModel::Serialization is one of your model's ancestors, then the simplest solution is just to add "include Rails3AMF::Serialization" at the top of your model implementation. I've never tried gem sets before, but it might be an issue with them, as everything works correctly using Bundler.

As an aside, feel free to post a bug to https://github.com/warhammerkid/rails3-amf/issues.

Comment: Can it be made such that we can add a `config` line in application.rb to include the `Rails3AMF::Serialization` module in all ActiveRecord models automatically?